# Iterables difference and common elements

Tags: python, list, counter, iterable

Given 2 iterables/lists, the goal is to extract the common and different elements from both lists.

For example, given:

```
x, y = [1,1,5,2,2,3,4,5,5], [2,3,4,5]
```

The goal is to achieve:

```
common = [2,3,4,5]
x_only = [1,1,5,2,5]
y_only = []
```

Explanation:

- when it comes to the element `2`, x has 2 counts and y has 1 count, so `[2]` will be in common and the other `[2]` will be in x_only.
- Similarly for `5`, x has 3 counts and y has 1 count. so `[5]` will be common and the other `[5,5]` will be in x_only.
- The order of the elements in `common`, `x_only` and `y_only` is not important.

I've tried:

```
from collections import Counter

x, y = [1,1,5,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5]

x_only = list((Counter(x) - Counter(y)).elements())
y_only = list((Counter(y) - Counter(x)).elements())
common = list((Counter(x) & Counter(y)).elements())
```

The above attempt achieves the objective but it seems a little redundant in repeating the multiple sets/counter subtraction and intersection. It will work for well for small iterables but not a large list e.g. 1-10 billion items.

Comment: 5 and 2 are not "only" in x

Comment: What's stopping you from creating each counter once and assigning it to a variable? instead of instantiating 6

Comment: Your inputs are different for each of your examples, which creates some confusion.

Comment: Surely x_only should be [1,1] as they're the only values in x that are not in y

Comment: @Codist: They're differencing *counts*, not unique elements. `x` has more `5`s than `y` (in both examples, though the examples disagree on how many), so the excess survive.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Technically, nine, since each of the not-in-place binary operators produces another `Counter`.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is fine, just remove the redundancy by only constructing each unique `Counter` once, by making the intersection *first* so less work is done to compose the unique results, and this will let you do most of the work in place (so only three `Counter` objects constructed, not nine):

```
from collections import Counter

x, y = [1,1,5,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5]

cx = Counter(x)
cy = Counter(y)
both = cx & cy
cx -= both
cy -= both
x_only = list(cx.elements())
y_only = list(cy.elements())
common = list(both.elements())
```

It's more lines, but it's less work being done, and any given line is far less complex.